# Computing sd() with irregular rolling windows in r

Tags: r, rolling-computation, standard-deviation

```
df <- structure(list(investor = c("INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1"), 
                     asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), 
                     datetime = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", 
                                  "2010-01-08", "2010-01-19"), 
                     portfolio = c(10, 0, 5, 2, 0)), 
                     operation = c(10, -10, 5, -3, -2), 
                     marketprice = c(10, 11, 12, 25, 5),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Hi, I have this type of dataset for which I want to compute the `sd()` of the marketprice but I want it to be computed on irregular interval which will be the holding time for each position.

For example the first position here is the `sd()` computed for the first two rows, then the `portfolio` quantity goes to zero, hence the `sd()` must stop so I'll have `sd(row1) , sd(row2)`, where the row1 is the sd computed on a price equal to 10, while row 2 is the sd computed over 10 and 11. Then again for rows 3/4/5 I need the same computations.

I have a dataset which consists of 4000 investors and 6000 different assets, so the computation must be on all those combinations.
I already computed something which I paste down here:

```
mutate(datetime = as.Date(datetime, "%Y-%m-%d")) %>% 
  group_by(investor, asset) %>% 
  arrange(datetime) %>% 
  mutate(grp.pos = cumsum(lag(portfolio, default = 1) == 0)) %>%
  group_by(investor, asset, grp.pos) %>% 
  mutate(holding = datetime - datetime[1])
```

which allows me to compute the holding time of a position updating that day after day iff the portfolio remains positive and that goes to zero if the portfolio is equal to zero.

I don't know how to do the same for R, I've seen something about rolling windows but that's not what I'm lookin for.
I'm not so smart with R so I'm stuck here.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the code to produce df in the question so we will use the input in the Note at the end.  Also we create a second investor giving df2 so that we can test this.
Grouping by investor and asset, create a grouping variable which creates a new group each time the portfolio is 0 and for each such group calculate the sd from the start of the group to the current row  using rollapplyr.  One cannot compute the sd for 1 point so the first row of each group will have an sd of NA.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df2 %>%
  group_by(investor, asset) %>%
  group_by(group = rev(cumsum(rev(portfolio == 0))), .add = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(sd = rollapplyr(marketprice, 1:n(), sd)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-group)
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 10 x 7
   investor asset datetime   portfolio operation marketprice     sd
   <chr>    <chr> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 INV_1    x     2010-01-01        10        10          10 NA    
 2 INV_1    x     2010-01-02         0       -10          11  0.707
 3 INV_1    x     2010-01-03         5         5          12 NA    
 4 INV_1    x     2010-01-08         2        -3          25  9.19 
 5 INV_1    x     2010-01-19         0        -2           5 10.1  
 6 INV_2    x     2010-01-01        10        10          10 NA    
 7 INV_2    x     2010-01-02         0       -10          11  0.707
 8 INV_2    x     2010-01-03         5         5          12 NA    
 9 INV_2    x     2010-01-08         2        -3          25  9.19 
10 INV_2    x     2010-01-19         0        -2           5 10.1
```

We can double check the values in the sd column.

```
sd(df2$marketprice[1])
## [1] NA

sd(df2$marketprice[1:2])
## [1] 0.7071068

sd(df2$makeprice[3])
## [1] NA

sd(df2$marketprice[3:4])
## [1] 9.192388

sd(df2$marketprice[3:5])
## [1] 10.14889
```

and the last 5 rows would have the same values for sd as the first 5 rows.

### Note

```
df <- structure(list(investor = c("INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1", "INV_1"), 
                     asset = c("x", "x", "x", "x", "x"), 
                     datetime = c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", "2010-01-03", 
                                  "2010-01-08", "2010-01-19"), 
                     portfolio = c(10, 0, 5, 2, 0), 
                     operation = c(10, -10, 5, -3, -2), 
                     marketprice = c(10, 11, 12, 25, 5)),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
df2 <- rbind(df, transform(df, investor = "INV_2"))
```